# Plotting using a Dataset, setting the color based on one column and plot markers based off another column

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, dataset

The set-up: I was able to generate some data and I merged it all together into one big matrix (exported and uploaded over here for use in this problem: **EDIT: removed**). When you download the data I exported, the columns that shouldn't be numeric will be imported as such. You can convert the data using:

```
bDat = Table[{bDat[[i, 1]], bDat[[i, 2]], ToString[bDat[[i, 3]]], ToString[bDat[[i, 4]]], ToString[bDat[[i, 5]]], ToString[bDat[[i, 6]]], ToString[bDat[[i, 7]]]}, {i, Length@dTry}]
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do that, but that's what I quickly typed up that worked. Otherwise the plotting won't work. Then, I convert it to a dataset object so I can label the columns as such:

```
BigDat = Dataset[bDat];
BigDat = BigDat[All, <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2, "actual cluster" -> 3, "k means" -> 4, 
"k medoids" -> 5, "spectral" -> 6, "agglomerate" -> 7|>];
```

As a note, all values except those in the "x" and "y" columns should be strings. Now I know if I use GatherBy I could use ListPlot and the data will be colored based on the column that I gathered the data by, like so:

```
ListPlot[BigDat[GroupBy[Key["actual cluster"]], All, {"x", "y"}]]
```

[image]

The the problem I am having is this: I would like to add plot markers to this plot, but I want the plot markers to be *based off another column*. For example, I want to color the data by the "actual cluster" column, and then I want to give each point a plot marker based off the "k means" column.

I thought maybe

```
PlotMarkers -> BigData[All,"k means"]
```

or

```
PlotMarkers -> BigDat[GroupBy[Key["k means"]], All, {"x", "y"}]
```

might work since it gives you the list of values in that column in the former or in the latter, clusters the data by that column, but it didn't work the way I expected. PlotMarkers - Automatic just coordinates the plot markers with the colors, which isn't what I am after either. I'm not very familiar at all about how to use dataset objects or plotting them, so I am having difficulty figuring out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I downloaded your dataset, but your `ListPlot` command plots an empty chart for me.

Comment: I exported the data as a csv, so it appears all the columns that shouldn't be numeric, are. If you try the code I added to the question on the imported data, it will work, because using GatherBy and then trying to plot, it can't plot with numbers but instead seems to work fine with strings.

Comment: ok, thanks, I missed the earlier condition. After transforming with `BigDat = BigDat[
  All, {"actual cluster" -> ToString, "k means" -> ToString, 
   "k medoids" -> ToString, "spectral" -> ToString, 
   "agglomerate" -> ToString}]`, I get essentially the same plot.

Comment: Apparently, Dataset selectors are quite sensitive to what kind of names do other columns have.

Comment: Much neater way to convert that than what I had! I didn't realise you could just do that.

Comment: Yep. I have a love/hate relationship with `Dataset` - it's super powerful, but with sometimes weird syntax and its own quirks.

Comment: Why did you delete the link to the data?

Comment: It was removed from the git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bd = Import[
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LuciaIllari/GettingStarted/master/bigdat.csv"];

dS = Dataset[MapAt[ToString, bd, {All, 3 ;;}]];

dS = dS[All, <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2, "actual cluster" -> 3, 
    "k means" -> 4, "k medoids" -> 5, "spectral" -> 6, "agglomerate" -> 7|>];

ClearAll[labeling]
labeling[index_: 97, fsize_: 16] := Apply[ Labeled[{#, #2}, 
      Style[#3, FontSize -> fsize, FontColor -> (ColorData[index]@FromDigits@#4)], 
      Center] &, #, {-2}] &;

lpdata = dS[GroupBy["actual cluster"] /* labeling[], 
    All, {"x", "y", "k means", "actual cluster"}];

ListPlot[lpdata, BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[0], 
   PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, "LegendMarkers" -> {"Bubble", 10}, 
     LegendLabel -> "actual cluster"], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking to do.

Comment: @Jony, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the data:

```
BigDat = Dataset[
   Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LuciaIllari/GettingStarted/master/bigdat.csv"]];
BigDat = BigDat[
  All, <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2, "actual cluster" -> 3, "k means" -> 4, 
   "k medoids" -> 5, "spectral" -> 6, "agglomerate" -> 7|>];
BigDat = BigDat[
  All, {"actual cluster" -> ToString, "k means" -> ToString, 
   "k medoids" -> ToString, "spectral" -> ToString, 
   "agglomerate" -> ToString}];
```

I played with this problem a bit and found *a solution*, but it's not pretty. Basically, `ListPlot` doesn't allow colors and markers to differ. What you can do, though, is to plot several charts, each with its own plot marker, and combine them with `Show`:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[<|"1" -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, "2" -> {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}|>, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 7}}, PlotMarkers -> "1"],
 ListPlot[<|"1" -> {{5, 5}}, "2" -> {{6, 6}, {7, 7}}|>, 
  PlotMarkers -> "2", PlotLegends -> None]]
```

gives

[image]

Of course, you would also need to clean up the legend and do a bit of programming to generate the list of `ListPlot`s automatically, but it's doable.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing too. I changed the plot marker sizes and colors and then overlaid them to get an approximation of what I wanted. It's frustrating that color and markers seem so intertwined like this! Thanks for having a go at it, though. Appreciated.